# Broken Data Connections between Esri Maps for Office and ArcGIS Online after update?

Tags: arcgis-online, esri-maps-office

We have a workflow in place where a spreadsheet is updated daily with new location data, synced to ArcGIS Online (AGOL), and then viewed in an AGOL web map and web app for informational purposes. Every time AGOL pushes out an update, the data connection between that spreadsheet and AGOL is severed and the app becomes out of date, even though we keep syncing changes from Excel and the layer says that it's been udpated.

Esri has no solution since they can't recreate the issue because the issue only happens in the gray area between updates, even though they have a record that this happens to us literally every time there's an update.

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or decrease the frequency of failure on my end?

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to publish your data to a google spreadsheet which can be used as a dynamic service. https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/02/21/using-google-docs-in-your-arcgis-online-maps/

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use ArcServer and host data in a database, rather than excel. ArcGIS for Office is half-developed - meaning there are too many "bugs" to make it worthy of use. Server is much better and much more developed when it comes to offline or online data sync. Moving the info to a database on server will decrease failure on your end.